# Why the Carousel slider is displaying only the first image while getting the data from the api in flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, carousel, carousel-slider

[this is the error, I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhmxo.png)

If i use the static image url's it is working fine, but while getting the dynamic images from the Api only the first image is displaying and others images are not displaying. Images are stored in s3 bucket.

this is sample list [https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-photocart-images/public/photocart-images/1698667906_image_cropper_1698667801113.jpg,  https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-photocart-images/public/photocart-images/1698667908_image_cropper_1698667803676.jpg]

Comment: CAn you please share the image links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@budgetapp Inspect the URI for any non-alphabetic characters. In my case, I found a space character preceding 'https'. Alternatively, you can use the following code: `url.replaceAll('"', '');`